# for i in range(0, int(num[pos])): TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x

```
def validar(pergunta, min, max):
    x = int(input(pergunta))
    while((x < min) or (x > max)):
        print('Código Inválido')
        print('Digite um número inteiro entre 10000 e 30000')
        x = int(input(pergunta))
    return x

def calcular(num):
    print('Dígito          |', end='')
    pos = 0
    while pos < 5:
        for i in range(0, int(num[pos])):
            print(f'{i} |', end='')
            pos += 1
    print()
    print('Peso            |', end='')
    for peso in range(2, 7):
        print(f'{peso:^5} |', end='')
    print()
    print('Multiplicação   |', end='')
    soma = 0
    peso1 = 2
    resto = 0
    for d in range(0, 5):
        for digito in num:
            resultado = int(digito[d]) * peso1
            soma += resultado
            peso1 += 1
            resto = soma % 7
            print(f'{resultado:^5} |', end='')
    print(f'   Soma todos = {soma}')
    print('-' * 75)
    print(f'                                                     Resto de {soma} por 7 = {resto}')
    print('-' * 75)
    print(f'{int(num[0])} - {resto}')
    print('------')
    return f'{num}-{resto}'

digito = validar('Digite o código do produto: ', 10000, 30000)

calcular(digito)
```

Comment: Por favor, explique exatamente qual é a sua dúvida e como podemos lhe ajudar. Não jogue simplesmente o código em uma pergunta.

Comment: Para saber melhor como fazer uma pergunta, clique [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8046/101).

Comment: Votei para fechar como precisando de mais detalhes, mas me equivoquei. O Voto de fechamento correto é devido a qualidade. Na função `validar()` o retorno é sempre um inteiro `x = int(input(pergunta))` o que implica que na linha `for i in range(0, int(num[pos])):` sempre será gerado um erro pois `num` é o retorno de `validar()` e sendo um inteiro não pode ser fatiado `num[pos]`. O problema pode ser facilmente detectado [fazendo a depuração do código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/137387).

Comment: Não da para saber certamente o quer fazer, mas analisando o seu código acho que você está tentando fazer isso https://ideone.com/Nnt81K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No código `for i in range(0, int(num[pos])):`, mais especificamente aqui: `int(num[pos])`, você está tentando acessar a posição 0 de um número inteiro, no caso esse número é a sua variável `num`.

Esse erro (**TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable**), segunda a documentação do python, ocorre quando você tenta acessar uma função como se fosse um objeto iterável. No caso, você está tentando tratar esse número inteiro como se fosse um [Array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), porém isso não funciona.